# How to auto register event in Unity Container

Tags: c#, events, .net-2.0, unity-container

I have a class with some event:

```
public class Foo

    {
        public event FooEventHandler FooEvent;

        public static void FooEvent(object sender, FooEventArgs fooEventEventArgs)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

This class used with Unity 1.2(because I am using it in .Net Framework 2.0).
Also I have **FooRepository** class, which implement business logic. In this class I want to add private method **OnFooEvent()**.
How auto register this event in Unity container?

```
IUnityContainer _cont=new UnityContainer();
_cont.RegisterType<IRepository,FooRepository>();
var foo=_cont.Resolve<FooRepository>();
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how Foo fits into this? How and where is Foo registered\resolved?

Comment: I need, that class FooRepository reacted on event FooEvent in class Foo. But object of class Foo is not pass to class FooRepository directly, so there is no standard way to call method OnFooEvent in class FooRepository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the EventBroker quickstart included with the Unity source code? Wiring events aren't something included by default, but the quickstart includes a sample extension that will auto-wire event senders and receivers.

Another option would be to look at the [Prism composite application guidance](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com). There's something in there called EventAggregator which can be used independently to also give you some of these capabilities.